# What script should I use to create a Self Extraction Directive in Innosetup?

Tags: self-extracting

I used to use iExpress add-on included in Windows,for years, to create a self extracting (temporary) PowerPoint presentation. However the process is now showing error messages (I suspect the issue might be due to Windows 11 but cannot be certain). I would like to do the same thing using Innosetup.
The SED created by iExpress used the command line: pptview.exe /L /S playlist.txt

Unfortunately, I have no coding expereince, so this issue has me stumped.
I would be so appreciative if someone could share a code that I can use.

I tried forming my own script below, but it does not work.

```
#define MyAppName "LESSON1EXT"
#define MyAppVersion "2.0"
#define AppName "LESSON 1"
#define MyAppExeName "LESSON 1.exe"

[Setup]
Uninstallable=no
CreateAppDir=no

[Run]
FileName: "{tmp}\pptview.exe /L /S playlist.txt"

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Files]
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\AUTORUN.INF"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\INTLDATE.DLL"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\Lesson 1 a-e WIDE.ppt"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\Level 3 - Unit 1.mp4"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\microsoft.vc80.crt.manifest"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags:  recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\msvcm80.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\msvcp80.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\MSVCR80.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\OGL.DLL"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\play.bat"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\playlist.txt"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\PPTVIEW.EXE"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\pptview.exe.manifest"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\PPVWINTL.DLL"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\PVREADME.HTM"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\SAEXT.DLL"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "L:\LEVEL 3 - LESSON 1\Lesson 1\Sec C.wav"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
```